# Placing a delimiter between each inline li but not at the edges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to place a delimiter between each inline `<li>` but so that it appears only between each item in the line and never in the beginning or at the end of a line?
If it can't be done with CSS then maybe can it be solved with JavaScript/jQuery?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pbxddo

```
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  li {
    display: inline;
    &:after {
    padding-left: 5px;
      content: '|';
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I don't think anyone understood... what I want is to remove EVERY delimiter that is in the beginning or at the end of each line, I don't know how to write it more clearly.

In this image this delimiters should be removed
[image]

So that the result will look like this

[image]

Comment: Don't tag javascript questions with java, they're not the same thing

Comment: Use Last-Chiled

Comment: @JonK - have you seen this about java / javascript? This one is hilarious, IMO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245073

Comment: @JonK Sorry, I am aware of the difference, I just typed java and I thought I saw javascript as a first tag.. I was already half asleep

Answer (score 1):

Use `li:last-child` selector, like:

```
li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below, or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QGJVXd) (with SCSS).

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid #333;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul li:after {
  padding-left: 5px;
  content: '|';
}
ul li:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else</li>
  <li>Bananas, apples </li>
  <li>Tea and cookies</li>
  <li>Football or soccer</li>
  <li>sky, earth, trees, nature</li>
  <li>Furniture, painting, closet, bed, carpet</li>
  <li>window, clothes, light, door</li>
  <li>Something else in the room</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not()` pseudo class and select all `li` elements except last one.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '|';
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a different approach than all of the (correct) :last-child answers.

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors): `+`.  This selects the second `li` that is immediately preceded by an `li`.  In your context, this will select all but the first `li` elements:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  li {
    display: inline;
  }
  li + li {
    &:before {
    padding-right: 5px;
      content: '|';
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a working snippet demonstrating your example:

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid #333;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
ul li + li:before {
  padding-right: 5px;
  content: '|';
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
  <li>Something</li>
  <li>Something else</li>
  <li>Bananas, apples </li>
  <li>Tea and cookies</li>
  <li>Football or soccer</li>
  <li>sky, earth, trees, nature</li>
  <li>Furniture, painting, closet, bed, carpet</li>
  <li>window, clothes, light, door</li>
  <li>Something else in the room</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Personally, I prefer this method because it's less verbose, and doesn't require "overrides".

Answer (score 0):

You can change your css to this:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px;
  li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    &:after {
    padding-left: 5px;
      content: '|';
    }
  }
  li:last-child {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 20px;
    &:after {
    padding-left: 5px;
      content: '';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @cale_b are you sure about that?